# Variable always undefined with await Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to test a function, and in that function a variable is created and assigned a value.

But the payload constant is always undefined.

**campaigns-card.component.ts**

```
async ngOnInit() {
    const { uid } = await this.auth.currentUser
    const { payload } = await this.firestore.surveysUsers(this.survey.id).doc(uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(first()).toPromise();
    this.completed = payload.exists
  }
```

**component-card.component.spec.ts**

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    fireStoreServiceMock.surveysUsers.and.returnValue({ 
      doc: () => { return {
        snapshotChanges: () => { return {
          pipe: () => { return {
            toPromise: () => { return { exists: true }}
          }}
        }}
      }}
    });
  }));

describe('tests in delete', () => {
    it('should update surveys', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      component.delete().then(() => {
      });
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick();

      expect(fireStoreServiceMock.surveys).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(snackBarMock.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
  });
```

**error**

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'exists' of undefined
    at CampaignsCardComponent.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/modules/campaigns/pages/campaigns-card/campaigns-card.component.ts:43:4)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:71:42)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:372:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:126:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:371:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.js:28535:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:371:1)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:134:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:1276:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there. The issue is that this is an observable and you shouldn't be mocking the `pipe` function on it but return an observable from the function call.

Try this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    fireStoreServiceMock.surveysUsers.and.returnValue({ 
      doc: () => { return {
        snapshotChanges: () => of({ exists: true }) // mock the observable with of
        }}
      }}
    });
  }));
```

I may have messed up the brackets ({  }) with the changes but that should do it.

Comment: I made this change, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: I managed to solve, as it is a const, I needed to return a payload object with exists inside.